# jQuery Scroller Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I'm currently trying to implement an up and down button (floating menu) on my portfolio website to scroll a certain amount down the page. For example I would click the down button and it would scroll 100px down and vice versa.

I am currently using this code to scroll to an a specific anchor when a button is clicked but I just want to modify it to shift up or down a set amount of pixels when clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*=#jump]').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,") == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,") && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var $target = $(this.hash);
            $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if ($target.length) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The current link in html is : `<a class="jump" href="#jump">Back To Top</a>`

which scrolls to the anchor : `<a id="jump" href="#"></a>`

I assume someone would know what I mean straight away but ask me if you need more detail and I can provide an example of what I'm trying to achieve. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I realized that the example you gave in your comment had the scroll animated so you could see it happen. So I updated my answer to include code that shows how to animate the scroll down or up

Comment: Cheers. Big ups Anton :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's scrollTop() to adjust the scroll vertical scroll bar.

For instance if your button to scroll down has an id of `scrollDownButton` and you want to scroll down the page by 100px then the following code will do that.

```
$('#scrollDownButton').click( function() {
    var currPosition = $('body').scrollTop();
    $('body').scrollTop(currPosition + 10);
});
```

`scrollTop()` will give you the current position of the vertical scroll bar and `scrollTop(value)` will set it to the given position.

If you want to scroll up the page then subtract from the current value rather than add.

**Note:** You want to select whichever element has the scroll bar. In the above example it was the `<body>`, but `<html>` is also a common element. Also scrollTop() was implemented in JQuery 1.2.6 make sure your version is new enough.

**Update: How to animate the scroll.**

If you want to animate the scroll and see it happen rather than just jump down or up you can use the following code:

```
$('#scrollDownButton').click( function() {
    var currPosition = $('body').scrollTop();
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: currPosition+100}, 'slow');
})
```

**Update for Ryan**

Here is the code for your specific page.

```
$('document').ready( function() {
    $('#scrollDownButton').click( function() {
        var currPosition = $('html').scrollTop();
        $('html').animate({scrollTop: currPosition+100}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try this out and reply back later if it works. Im guessing it will work the same way to go up 10 pixels?

Comment: To go up you want to subtract 10 from the current value. You don't have to worry about going below zero since jquery is smart enough to not care.

Comment: Thank you Anton. Very quick answer! A first time using StackOverflow, very good community here.

Comment: No problem glad to have helped. :D

Comment: Hi @Anton It still does not work and I have done everything you said.

Comment: What does it do? Also is your page big enough because if there is no scroll bar it won't scroll it up or down.

Comment: Yes there is a scroll bar and the page is quite large. I put your code as it was in a .js file then link it in my header so thats all sorted. And I have already imported the jquery js lib so that is sorted as I already have js on my current page. I simply create a link such as <a id="scrollDownButton" href=""></a>. Then nothing happens when I click on this. Im gathering something is going wrong in the JS? I really appreciate your help :D @Anton

Comment: I think I figured out why. Remove your href="" attribute for the link, so it looks like this:
                              <a id="scrollDownButton" >Click Me!</a>.
It should work when you click it now.

Comment: Ok ill have a go at that now :)

Comment: No it's still not working??????? Is there anything that could have been missed in the JS?

Comment: I don't believe so, since I made a working version of it on my computer. The other problem could be that the element with the scrollbar isn't the body tag but another element such as a div. If you have a link to you page I could also look around there.

Comment: I have it running locally right now but here is the html doc. http://pastie.org/1523174 , have a look to see if you can spot anything. The links are at the bottom of the doc. @Anton

Comment: Figured it out. Turns out your scroll bar was on your <html> not your <body> See my updated answer for the new JS code.

Comment: The JS file is exactly as you pasted it.

Comment: Its probably a problem with us selecting the wrong tag. If your ok with sending me the css, js file and images for the page I could probably find the problem, but it is hard to see where it is going wrong when we have two different copies of the page. If your not comfortable sending the files then I suggest looking at the page with firebug to get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: Here is the zipped folder. The index.html is the only page I want to implement this on so just look at that html file. http://www.4shared.com/dir/8NawOLaz/sharing.html

Comment: It turned out to be 3 little things. The first is that scrollTop() was implemented in jquery 1.2.6 and you are using jquery 1.2.3 . So you need to get a new version of jquery.
Second the code was subtracting 100 instead of adding for scroll down so it looked like it was doing nothing.
Finally the js code needed to be be run after the document had loaded.
I have updated my code in the answer for you so copy and paste that into your scrolled.js also remember to get a newer version of jquery.

Comment: I noticed that in different browsers the two link elements would render in different places. I'm assuming this is going to change later on, but I wanted to mention that if the link elements appear at the bottom of the page on your browser then the down link will seemingly do nothing but don't be fooled by that. I was myself for a little while :)

Comment: :( sorry to bother but I have fixed all off those and nothing. Coda is telling me that $('html').scrollTop() is not a function. I did not get this before I updated to the latest jquery 1.2.5

Comment: Just fixed it, had to put 'body,html' rather than just 'html'. Cheeerssssss

Comment: Noooooooooooooooooooooooooo it scrolls to a set position. Eg if i click it and it moves to that position t wont move again. Because its always just adding 100px from the top of the page. I want it to add 100px from the current pos each time :)

Comment: It shouldn't be doing that. That is why we call .scrollTop() and set it to currPosition. Also the jquery website says you need 1.2.6 or higher not 1.2.5. Are you sure it was only adding 100px from the top? Also what browser are you using?

Comment: Fixed all now. I needed to just set it to 'body' not html. Everything is working now. Thanks for the great help you have given!

Comment: No problem I'm glad we finally fixed it. I'm surprised that even after I had a zip of your folder that we had slightly different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to use jQuery's ScrollTo and simply specify an offset amount.

[jQuery ScrollTo](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/scrollTo/)

For example, you could have it always scroll to the same element, but change the offset value by increments of 100px, ect.

But I'd imagine there is a much better way than this out there...

Comment: Here is an example of a website with what im trying to achieve http://www.gregponchak.com/